# How to get data from API response using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, laravel, bitcoin, coinbase-api

Im using an API, and I need to display the data in my blade view. Im having trouble doing that. This is what I have in my controller:

```
public function index() {

    // secret ....
    // key....

    $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
        $client = Client::create($configuration);

        $BTCSellPrice = $client->getSellPrice('BTC-USD');
        dd($BTCSellPrice);

    return view('welcome', compact(
            'BTCSellPrice'
        ));
}
```

I get back this:

[image]

I tried calling it in the front-end these ways:

```
{{ $BTCSellPrice }}
{{ $BTCSellPrice->amount }}
{{ $BTCSellPrice['amount'] }}
{{ $BTCSellPrice[0] }}
```

But keep on getting errors, like:

```
Cannot use object of type Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money as array
```

Do I need to pass it through a collection or something?

Comment: `$BTCSellPrice->amount` should work fine. If you're trying to display all the types to check which works, even a single one can cause page errors and prevent others from loading.

Comment: Get this error when using your method: ``` Cannot access private property Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money::$amount ```

Comment: nevermind i found the coinbase php library and looked up the class myself. Updated my answer. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the class object being returned and figured out what you need from https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php/blob/master/src/Value/Money.php

```
{{ $BTCSellPrice->getAmount() }}
{{ $BTCSellPrice->getCurrency() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access private fields from other classes. To do this you have to change your private attribute to public ones or write some Getters like this:

```
class Money {

    private $amount;
    private $currency;

    public function getAmount() {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function getCurrency() {
        return $this->currency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@foreach ($BTCSellPrice as $temp)
   <h3> {{$temp}}</h3>
@endforeach
```

Comment: no that does not work, it displays nothing, tried $temp->amount too